# Unable to solve differential... $yy'=y+1$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The differential equation is:

$$yy'=y+1$$I've been trying to solve this problem all evening, but I cannot figure it out, and none of the online calculators show me *the steps* on how to find the solution. Could anybody help me out?

Comment: It's separable, no?  I mean the variable $x$ doesn't even appear explicitly.

Comment: It is separable, yes

Comment: So...just isolate the terms involving $y$ on one side and $dx$ on the other.

Comment: It is both separable and automonous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be reduced to just some calculus, by writing $dy/dx = \frac{y+1}{y}$. This can now be separated, giving

$$\frac{y \  dy}{y+1} = dx$$

Which can be integrated by making a substitution to give

$$y - \log(|y+1|) + C = x$$

I don't think you will be able to solve this explicitly for $y$ though.

Comment: I think it may be it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: $-(y+1)e^{-(y+1)}=c\,e^{-x}$ can be solved as $y=-1-W(c\,e^{-x})$ using the Lambert-W function.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{y\,dy}{y+1}=dx.$$

By integration from $x_0$,
$$y-y_0-\log\frac{y+1}{y_0+1}=x-x_0.$$